# Editing the question about FIFA being against video reviews (the 2nd most voted question on Sports SE)

Tags: discussion, editing

The question about [Why is FIFA against adding instant replay to the game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-is-fifa-against-adding-instant-replay-to-the-game) needs to be edited because the premises in the question are old.

The wording in the title and body of the question should be changed from *"is"* to *"was"*, but I didn't want to do it without discussing on meta because it's [**the second most voted question on this site**](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). Although I wrote an [updated answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/19915/12991) to this question, it's too low in the feed to be noticed and thus maybe other answers to the question should be edited too.

What should we do about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing an erroneous premise of the question is part of what a great answer should do.

The question is historical and should be kept from that perspective, with answers added or updated to reflect the change of FIFA opinion and regulations, as well as note that this change is (currently) quite recent.

Comment: So, do you think that we should update every single answer and add same notes about the changes?

Comment: Existing answers should be left to the users who posted them, although that also makes the vote counts misleading - even better is to leave old answers the same - with a new answer addressing the change in opinion/process being able to get its own attention separately.